# Native way to return path of currently running R binary

Tags: r

Is there a **native** method to show the full path of the current running R binary (e.g. returning `/usr/bin/R` as a string)?

Comment: Is R.home("bin") what you are looking for?

Comment: @Sebastian yes! Thanks. This is a proper answer.

Comment: If `R_HOME` environment variable is changed, `R.home("bin")` will not return the path to the currently used R binary but a path relative to `R_HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sebastian points out in the comments, the `component` argument of the `R.home()` function can be used to return a string with the full path of the R binary:

```
R.home("bin")
```

Other values can be used to show different paths related to your R installation.